# Проблемы при создании своего stl контейнера и итератора к нему

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl

Пытаюсь сделать свой контейнер и итератор к нему. При описании метода `begin()` получаю 2 ошибки компиляции:

```
C2143 Missing ';' before '<'

C2238 Unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

Само определение:

```
typename MyIterator<data_type> begin() {};
```

Пройдясь по `msdn` выяснил, что скорее всего компилятор не понимает тип данных, который я хочу получить от `begin()`, в связи с этим вопрос, как реализовать это?

Весь созданный мной заголовочный файл:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

namespace lab

{
    //--------------------------------
    // SUPPORTING STRUCT FOR CONTAINER
    //--------------------------------
    template <class data_type> struct _list

{
    // field for contained data
    data_type data;
    // pointer for the next member
    struct _list<data_type> * next;
    // pointer for the previous member
    struct _list<data_type> * previous;
};


//----------------
// CONTAINER CLASS
//----------------
template <class data_type> class List

{

private:

    _list<data_type> * head; // first element from the list
    _list<data_type> * tail; // last element from the list
    size_t list_size;        // number of elements

public:

    List();
    ~List();


    typename MyIterator <data_type> begin() {};

    void push_back(data_type data);
    size_t size();                                  // returns number of elements
};


template <class data_type> List<data_type>::List()

{
    head = tail = NULL;
    list_size = NULL;
}

template <class data_type> List<data_type>::~List()

{
    _list<data_type> * cur = this->head;
    _list<data_type> * tmp = NULL;

    while (cur)

    {
        tmp = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = tmp;
    }
}

template <class data_type> size_t List<data_type>::size() 

{ 
    return list_size; 
}

template <class data_type> void List<data_type>::push_back(data_type data)

{
    if (!tail)
    {
        head = new _list<data_type>;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->previous = NULL;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        _list<data_type> * temp = new _list<data_type>;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->previous = tail->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
        tail = temp;
    }
    this->list_size++;
}

// --------------------
// ITERATOR CLASS
// --------------------

template<class data_type> class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, data_type>

{
    friend class List<data_type>;

private:

    _list<data_type> * p;

public:

    MyIterator(const MyIterator &it);
    MyIterator(data_type * p);
    bool operator != (MyIterator const & other) const;
    bool operator == (MyIterator const & other) const; 
    typename MyIterator::reference operator * () const;
    MyIterator& operator ++ ();
};

template<typename data_type> MyIterator<data_type>::MyIterator(data_type * __p) : p(__p) {  }

template<typename data_type> MyIterator<data_type>::MyIterator(const MyIterator & it) : p(it.p) { }

template<typename data_type> bool MyIterator<data_type>::operator != (MyIterator const & other) const

{
    return p->data != other.p->data;
}

template<typename data_type> bool MyIterator<data_type>::operator == (MyIterator const & other) const

{
    return p->data == other.p->data;
}

template<typename data_type> typename MyIterator<data_type>::reference MyIterator<data_type>::operator * () const

{
    return p->data;
}

template<typename data_type> MyIterator<data_type> & MyIterator<data_type>::operator ++ ()

{
    p = p->next;
    return *this;
}
}
```

Comment: Указание компилятору, что MyIterator<data_type> это тип данных, взял с того же MSDN, без него тоже не работает

Comment: Ничего подобного с `typename` на MSDN нет. `typename` - бывает нужно, но используется оно совсем не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас класс `MyIterator` объявлен после класса `List`. Естественно, компилятор его не видит. Класс итератора нужно либо объявлять заранее, либо делать вложенным типом для контейнера (причем вначале класса, т.к. внутри класса порядок объявления типов тоже важен)

Comment: Спасибо! Объявил прототип класса итератора и все получилось